# How can I use a component like react-image-editor for cropping an image in react-admin

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-admin, toast-ui-image-editor

I am using `React-Admin` and I need to use/create a component for cropping an image (profile image) and storing it as a base64-image.
I found `@toast-ui/react-image-editor` better than other libraries but I have a problem with that. In `React-Admin` when we use `ImageInput` like this:

```
<ImageInput multiple label="Gallery" source="gallery" accept="image/*">
    <ImageField source="src" title="title" />
</ImageInput>
```

the data can be loaded from the source (in Edit mode) and it will be stored there, but when we use other components like what I have mentioned, I need to know how can I pass the data as a source to that. It doesn't matter for me to use this library or any others... but I need one with simple usage.

Actually, my issue is with connecting the new component to the model that react-admin use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently written such a component, you can find it under the following link:
[EditableImageComponent](https://github.com/g3n35i5/shop-db2-react-admin/blob/master/src/shared/fields/EditableImageField.tsx).
I don't use `@toast-ui/react-image-editor` for this, like you do, but [ReactImageCrop](https://github.com/DominicTobias/react-image-crop), maybe the component will help you anyway. At the moment I have some bugs in the code (after the image is loaded, the crop has to be changed once before it is applied), but otherwise it works quite well so far.

**Edit**: In order to use this component in your EditView, simply call it like every other Input Component (it is assumed, that your target is called "imagename")

```
<EditableImage source="imagename" {...props} label="User image (Use the upload button to edit)"/>
```

[image: EditableImage component]

Answer (score 0):

I have use `@toast-ui/react-image-editor` as my image editor. i use modal to edit images in gallery. My simple code using react and bootstrap.

first import react image editor.

```
import 'tui-image-editor/dist/tui-image-editor.css';
import ImageEditor from '@toast-ui/react-image-editor';
```

if you use class component add this line.

```
export default class Example extends Component {
  editorRef = React.createRef();
}
```

or if you use funtional component add this line.

```
function Example() {
  const editorRef = React.createRef();
}
```

then call react image editor in the component.

```
<ImageEditor
 ref={this.editorRef}
 includeUI={{
 loadImage: {
  path: imagePath,
  name: imageName,
 },
 theme: myTheme,
 menu: [
       "filter",
        "crop",
        "flip",
        "resize",
        "rotate",
        "text",
       ],
 initMenu: "filter",
 uiSize: {
     width: "100%",
     height: "600px",
     },
menuBarPosition: "left",
}}
cssMaxHeight={500}
cssMaxWidth={700}
selectionStyle={{
cornerSize: 20,
rotatingPointOffset: 70,
}}
usageStatistics={false}

/>
```

[image]